# How to set default gas limit on Web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, gas-limit

Tired of getting outputs like

```
"Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]"
```

and having to specify gas limit on every smart contract call like

```
sc.endpoint(parameters, {gas:1000000});
```

I would like to know if there is any web3 command similar to

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = "...";
```

capable of define a new limit to gas consumed on my next transactions.

Variable **web3.eth.gasLimit** seems not to exist...

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr You can't do this with web3 .. yet. You can track progress of the proposal to improve web3, and add improvements such as promises and defaults in this ticket: [EIP68](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/68).

However, you can do something similar on the contract level with [truffle-artifactor](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-artifactor) (formerly called ether-pudding):

```
var myContract = MyContract.at("0x1234...");
myContract.defaults({
  gasLimit: "100000"
});
```

Or alternatively, the following is equivalent:

```
var myContract = MyContract.at("0x1234...", {gasLimit: "10000"});
```